# NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe, append

I was trying to create a dataframe with columns providing the statistics of the all the NFL games in a single week.
However in NFL two teams are given a 'bye' meaning they won't play in that week therefore there's no data for the game
When i don't use 'if game is not None' it gives the same "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'home'" for 'hteam = game.home' which means there's a missing data for home because of the bye ,but when i use it it still gives the same error ,however this time it is for the appending part. 
I don't really understand why because the data appending part is inside the if statement. 
Thanks in advance

I have tried indenting but it didn't really affect anything and gave me the same error

```
teams= ['KC','NYJ','ATL','BAL','PIT','ARI','JAX','OAK','PHI','IND','SEA','CAR','NYG','NO','MIA','TB','LAC']
df= pd.DataFrame(columns =["Home","Away","Win","hRushYds","hPassYds",
                           'hPuntAvg','hPenYds',"aRushYds","aPassYds",
                           'aPuntAvg','aPenYds',"hScore","aScore"])

def teamStats(h,data):
    w = 0
    game = nflgame.one(2017,1,h,h)
    if game is not None:
        hteam = game.home
        ateam = game.away
        hpass_yds = game.stats_home.passing_yds
        apass_yds = game.stats_away.passing_yds
        hscore = game.score_home
        ascore = game.score_away
        hrush_yds = game.stats_home.rushing_yds
        arush_yds = game.stats_away.rushing_yds
        hpen_yds = game.stats_home.penalty_yds
        apen_yds = game.stats_away.penalty_yds
        hpunt_avg = game.stats_home.punt_avg
        apunt_avg = game.stats_away.punt_avg
        if hteam == game.winner:
            w = 1
        data = data.append({'Home':hteam,'Away':ateam,'Win': w,
                           'hPassYds':hpass_yds,'aPassYds':apass_yds,'hScore': hscore,
                           'aScore':ascore,'hRushYds':hrush_yds,'aRushYds':arush_yds,
                           'hPenYds':hpen_yds,'aPenYds': apen_yds,'hPuntAvg':hpunt_avg,
                           'aPuntAvg': apunt_avg}, ignore_index=True)
        return data

for h in teams:
    df = teamStats(h,df)
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not return anything from `teamstats` when `game` is `None`.
Then you assign the return value to `df`.
So now, `df` might be `None` (in case `game` was none).
In the next loop iteration of `for h in teams` you try to insert this `df` (`==None`) into `teamstats` again, at what point it fails, because there is no `None.append`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, you're trying iterate over the `teams` list and append their stats to the data frame if they have stats to append. You are passing the data frame to the `teamStats` function and let it do the appending and return to new data frame, which you set to `df` in the loop.

That's not necessarily wrong, but I would prefer that the function would return the data to append (if there is data), and the appending would be done in the outer loop. I think this would be cleaner and less error prone.

With that in mind, I would rewrite your code like this:

```py
teams = ["KC", "NYJ", "ATL", "BAL", "PIT", "ARI", "JAX", "OAK",
         "PHI", "IND", "SEA", "CAR", "NYG", "NO", "MIA", "TB", "LAC"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Home", "Away", "Win", "hRushYds", "hPassYds",
                           "hPuntAvg", "hPenYds", "aRushYds", "aPassYds",
                           "aPuntAvg", "aPenYds", "hScore", "aScore"])


def team_stats(h):
    game = nflgame.one(2017, 1, h, h)
    if game is not None:
        return {
            "Home": game.home,
            "Away": game.away,
            "Win": int(game.home == game.winner),  # int(True) = 1, int(False) = 0
            "hPassYds": game.stats_home.passing_yds,
            "aPassYds": game.stats_away.passing_yds,
            "hScore": game.score_home,
            "aScore": game.score_away,
            "hRushYds": game.stats_home.rushing_yds,
            "aRushYds": game.stats_away.rushing_yds,
            "hPenYds": game.stats_home.penalty_yds,
            "aPenYds": game.stats_away.penalty_yds,
            "hPuntAvg": game.stats_home.punt_avg,
            "aPuntAvg": game.stats_away.punt_avg,
        }
    return None


for h in teams:
    stats = team_stats(h)
    if stats is not None:
        df = df.append(stats, ignore_index=True)
df
```

As you can see, the `team_stats` function returns the data to append (if there is data) and the loop checks if it needs to append the data or not. I prefer this approach because this way, the function doesn't change any external data (variables or data structures that were not defined in the function locally) so it's less likely to get errors because you forgot to return `data` in the case the game is `None` (see kawillzocken's answer).

Two last notes about pythonic code:

1. If your function returns `None` in a specific case, you should write `return None` explicitly even though writing `return` or letting the function reach the end of its body achieves the same result. That way, it's clearer that you want to return `None` and it may have helped you to catch that mistake. Use the other ways in functions that shouldn't return anything (void functions).
2. In python it's more conventional, according to [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), to write function names (and variables as well) in `small_letters_with_underscores_as_spaces`. So it's more conventional to write `team_stats` instead of `teamStats`. Of course it's personal preference, but I think it's a good practice to stick to conventions.